# Do I have to be affiliated with an institution to publish on arXiv? Is arXiv the right place to put it?

Tags: publications, arxiv, independent-researcher

I'm a high schooler who recently found a derivation of a trigonometric function over complex numbers. I typed it up as a LaTeX paper and know it's probably not publishable to an actual journal. I'm deciding if I should publish it to arXiv and when I tried registering as a user it asked for my affiliation. Is an affiliation necessary to register and publish? Is it even worth trying to publish?

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/i-want-to-submit-a-paper-to-arxiv-org-but-im-not-affiliated-to-an-institute-w

Comment: Incidentally, the stated policy is that ["arXiv accepts only submissions in the form of an article that would be refereeable by a conventional publication venue"](http://arxiv.org/help/moderation).  This is not always strictly enforced, and "refereeable by a conventional publication venue" is not such a high standard, but the general understanding is that if something wouldn't be worth publishing somewhere, then it's probably not worth posting on the arXiv.

Comment: On the other hand, a clever derivation could plausibly be published in the [College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal), so nothing is ruled out just by the fact that it's a derivation of a trigonometric identity over the complex numbers.  I agree with Captain Emacs's advice.

Comment: See also [Submitting to arXiv when unaffiliated](http://mathoverflow.net/q/12894/96907) in Math Overflow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Independently of whether you need an affiliation, this sounds like a well-known representation of trig formulas (Euler's formula). There is quite some theory involved with this, including and up to Galois theory. You should check with someone knowledgeable whether you indeed discovered anything new.

It's fun to discover new stuff, and it's a cool feeling to recover things that very smart people came up with, but, once you are there, you have to give it the reality check, which is the ultimate hallmark of the scientist.

Perhaps some friendly mathematician from the local college is happy to spare half an hour with a talented high schooler to give you at least an idea how novel the idea is or what else to try from this point on?

Answer (score 15):

I believe an affiliation is not necessary when registering, although their [help page](http://arxiv.org/help/registerhelp) only mentions that if you supply an affiliation, it has to be correct. If the signup form insists that you fill out the field, you can always write "None" or something like that. Note however opening a user account is only one part of submitting an article. In your case it is likely that you would need to be endorsed first for the category in which you want to submit. This would require you to find someone who has published a few papers in your category to endorse you. The arXiv recommends that endorsers do a quick check to see if the manuscript is appropriate for the arXiv or not. More information can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement).

That being said, Captain Emacs makes a good point, and it would be wise to first check if your work adds anything to what is already known and available.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need an academic affiliation.

I registered with arXiv a while back. I may or may not have entered the name of my employer (a large software company, in no way an academic institution). I have also been endorsed, so I could upload something. (I haven't done so yet, because I found [the process to be painfully cumbersome](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49386/4140).)

If you *must* fill in an affiliation field, I'd suggest you just put in the name of your high school, or "independent".

Comment: The first line is a bit misleading. The real answer is "yes, there does need to be an affiliation, either your own or that of someone who will personally endorse you."

Comment: @ChrisWhite: (1) The OP asked whether he *himself* needs an affiliation. (2) Are you sure that you need an affiliation to *endorse* someone, beyond just filling in "independent" in a mandatory field?

Comment: I disagree using your high school as an affiliation, at least without clearing it with the principal or equivalent first. Affiliations are usually taken to imply support/representation, and should be cleared with the institution. At universities, professors/etc. are hired to publish, so the authorization is implicit in their hiring. For commercial companies you need to clear it with your boss before publishing under the company's name. High schools should be no different. You should get permission from the school prior to putting their name on the paper.