# How to submit an article (for example, on arXiv) without being affiliated to any institution?

Tags: publications, mathematics, arxiv, independent-researcher, online-publication

The core of the problem is already in the title but I feel as i should add some more details.

I was doing some mathematics and, if there are no logical flaws or mistakes of any other nature (it seems that there are none) I managed to prove some result that, again, if it is proved with no errors, would, I believe, enrich the field in which it belongs.

Of course, I immediately started to think about arXiv.org and I decided that I want to submit an article there, but, when I was reading *help* section, there stands this, written:

> *Note: It is a violation of our policies to misrepresent your identity or institutional affiliation. Claimed affiliation should be current in the conventional sense: e.g., physical presence, funding, e-mail address, mention on institutional web pages, etc. Misrepresentation of identity or affiliation, for any reason, is possible grounds for immediate and permanent suspension.*

But, as you are aware by now, I do not belong to any institution and as such, am not affiliated with any, I am just an amateur that among all fields thinks about mathematics the most. So, I have stumbled upon this cautious note quoted above and do not know what to do.

So, I decided to write to all of you here to see what can be done in this case of mine. I am not 100% sure that among all sites this is the one most suited for this problem of mine (for example, I could have written this on MO Meta or MSE Meta) but surely I will try to welcome opinions and help, even if they do not resolve this issue that I am faced with.

What should be done?

EDIT: This is not a complete duplicate of the question mentioned in such a way as this one is a duplicate of that one because the body of the question mentioned goes like this:

"Assume you have already completed your undergrad and have been working for a number of years. Does one need to be part of a university or a learning institution to publish papers?"

But, I did not complete my undergrad and I am working for a number of years (independently). so, there are some similiarites but the question is not exactly the same, although answers seem to fit well.

Comment: See here for answers: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61628/do-i-have-to-be-affiliated-with-an-institution-to-publish-on-arxiv-is-arxiv-the?rq=1 https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/what-to-put-in-affiliation-field-when-submitting-paper-without-affiliation https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/does-one-need-to-be-affiliated-with-a-university-to-publish-papers https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/306/is-it-possible-take-take-part-in-a-research-project-if-im-not-a-part-of-a-unive

Comment: A question is marked as a duplicate if the answers apply equally. It's not necessary for every detail of the question to be the same.

Answer (score 21):

The text you found tells you that you must not claim some affiliation which you do not actually have. So either leave the affiliation field empty, or enter something like "Independent Researcher".

You will then probably have to go through the endorsement procedure. For that, you need some researchers that have published in the category you are aiming for before to state that they think you should be allowed to publish to the arXiv.

Answer (score 5):

My advice toward "what should be done" is to send the paper to a peer-reviewed journal.  Only by review will you learn (a) the value of what you've done, and (b) whether there are errors.  arxiv.org will not tell you this; it is just a repository.

As for *which* journal to send it to, that's another question entirely.  You should probably not try for the top journal(s) in the field, as they will have very high standards and little patience for someone without experience in writing papers.

Comment: +1 The arXiv approach is probably more suitable for someone who either has the experience to evaluate their own research, or the contacts to get others to review it. Sending a paper to a peer-reviewed journal gets some feedback.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I can evaluate my own research, because its mine, how could I even be able to do the research if I am not able to evalute it, right?

Comment: @Antoine Part of evaluating it is determining the novelty which requires a much broader view than just doing the research. And as for correctness, the hundreds of "proofs" of the Riemann hypothesis suggests that the author is not always qualified to judge that.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft OK, we can agree that some experts are armed with enough experience so that they can say some things about my research, that, maybe, I cannot. But what if nobody wants to read my work?

Comment: When you send it to a peer-reviewed journal, the journal (its editors) will send it to other experienced researchers who will then read and evaluate it - from an _independent_ position. Otherwise we wouldn't need peer-review: everyone should be convinced of their own research.